# Change background color of HyperLinkButton on MouseOver/MouseEnter in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am new to silverlight,will any one guide how can I do this.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XAML:**

```
<HyperlinkButton  Name="hyperlinkButton" Content="Change Background" MouseEnter="hyperlinkButton_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="hyperlinkButton_MouseLeave" />
```

**Code Behind:**

```
private void hyperlinkButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     hyperlinkButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}

private void hyperlinkButton_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     hyperlinkButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.windowspresentationfoundation.com/?p=679) is video tutorial "How to Style a Hyperlink Button". There you can see

```
How to change the color of a Hyperlink Button when the mouse is over it.
```

Source code for download is also available.

If you whant to do that as @BurkDigglers described, than you must handle `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events for each hyperlink button.